# Best practice to handle patch / delete in REST API

Tags: node.js, rest

I have a collection of Employees, on which CRUD operations can be performed.

I am working on 2 given endpoints

1. delete multiple employees in single API requests given the ids of the employees to be deleted is given in the body of the request.
2. update multiple employees using single API request.

Lets consider an example where one of the ID is not found in the list of employee ids to be deleted/deleted/updated, in this case should the whole request be rejected ? or delete the existing ones and send error response only for the not found id?

It would be helpful, if you could help me with the best practice.

Thank you,
KK

Comment: Whichever scenario better fits your business requirements should be implemented. There's no one good answer.

Comment: I personally prefer to delete/update the items that exists, and ignore "non existing" items. If you provide only one id and its not found return a 404. If you provide 2 ids, and just one is not found return a 200 and ignore the one that does not exists. And so for 2+.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I have currently implemented such that we provide multi-status 207 as response code, and each object contains the success / failure message.